# jquery simple image slider w/ajax

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery, slider

I have a page with lots of images on it, and only want to load extra images on demand.  IE if the user clicks on it or mouses over, whatever.  Most if not all of the sliders i've seen use the hidden attribute with all the elements getting loaded at once, which would cause undue burden in my case.

I liked: http://nivo.dev7studios.com/ but it has no such feature.

Anyone know of an ajax slider preferably using jquery?

Thanks

Comment: Pls, how did you solve your question?

Comment: i haven't yet.  jcarousel would work, but it's more complicated than i need. ;-(

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do that with jcarousel:
http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

The trick is to pass the images one by one in javascript, not in html, if not, there are always loaded beforehand.

The code would be:

```
var mycarousel_itemList = [
{url:"/im/a.jpg", title: ""},{url:"/im/b.jpg", title: ""}];

listaimg=document.createElement('ul');
jQuery(listaimg).attr('id','mycarousel');
jQuery(listaimg).addClass('jcarousel-skin-tango');
jQuery('#containercarousel').append(listaimg);
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({   auto: 9,wrap: 'last', visible: 1,scroll:1, size: mycarousel_itemList.length,
    itemLoadCallback: {onBeforeAnimation: mycarousel_itemLoadCallback}

   });


function mycarousel_itemLoadCallback(carousel,state){for(var i=carousel.first;i<=carousel.last;i++){if(carousel.has(i)){continue}if(i>mycarousel_itemList.length){break};

carousel.add(i,mycarousel_getItemHTML(mycarousel_itemList[i-1]));


  }
};
function mycarousel_getItemHTML(item)
{


  var img = new Image();
                 $J(img).load(function () {

// whatever you want to do while loading.
    }).attr('src', item.url);
 return "<li><img src=\"" + item.url + "\" width=\"770\" alt=\"\" /></li>";

}
```