# How to avoid pre-loading images when using jQuery Cycle Plugin

Tags: jquery, cycle, preload

I have a slideshow (jQuery Cycle) with large images, and would like to AVOID pre-loading all the images when the page loads.

Instead, I'd like to only load the first image, and have the rest load after the user CLICKS on it.

I'd really appreciate any ideas! Javascript newbie here... Thanks so much!!!!!

Comment: Can you point us to any code examples?

Comment: What about using the "before" option in jQuery Cycle? What's the difference between these 3 options?                                 >>> 1. http://tinyurl.com/29vl5t4                                   >>> 2. http://tinyurl.com/24o2stc                                   
>>> 3. http://tinyurl.com/2flybss                                   How can I use one of those methods and bind it to a click on the first image?

Answer (score 2):

So the best solution i found was here: http://tinyurl.com/24o2stc
Using the "before" option from jQuery Cycle, it only loads the first 2 slides, and adds the next one as you keep clicking thru the slideshow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, but the concept is to load the images in javascript, not in HTML because you could not prevent loading everything if it is in HTML.

Look at my answer to this question:

[jquery simple image slider w/ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949913/jquery-simple-image-slider-w-ajax/3949945#3949945)

"I think you can do that with jcarousel:

http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

The trick is to pass the images one by one in javascript, not in html, if not, they are always loaded beforehand.

The code would be:

```
var mycarousel_itemList = [
{url:"/im/a.jpg", title: ""},{url:"/im/b.jpg", title: ""}];

listaimg=document.createElement('ul');
jQuery(listaimg).attr('id','mycarousel');
jQuery(listaimg).addClass('jcarousel-skin-tango');
jQuery('#containercarousel').append(listaimg);
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({   auto: 9,wrap: 'last', visible: 1,scroll:1, size: mycarousel_itemList.length,
    itemLoadCallback: {onBeforeAnimation: mycarousel_itemLoadCallback}

   });


function mycarousel_itemLoadCallback(carousel,state){for(var i=carousel.first;i<=carousel.last;i++){if(carousel.has(i)){continue}if(i>mycarousel_itemList.length){break};

carousel.add(i,mycarousel_getItemHTML(mycarousel_itemList[i-1]));


  }
};
function mycarousel_getItemHTML(item)
{


  var img = new Image();
                 $J(img).load(function () {

// whatever you want to do while loading.
    }).attr('src', item.url);
 return "<li><img src=\"" + item.url + "\" width=\"770\" alt=\"\" /></li>";

}
```

"

Comment: thanks for the suggestion netadictos! But just to keep it simpler (not have to add jcarousel too), could I achieve this by using that "before" option in jquery Cycle I mentioned above? Do you know how I could bind it to a click on the first image? Thanks!

Comment: @Guilherme - not at all, you can always upvote, nevertheless, I have verified the before option with firebug in network tab, and all the images are preloaded. Could you look at it pls and report?

Comment: I played around with the "before" option from the jQuery Cycle plugin, and it works. I confirmed it with firebug!
It seems cleaner this way so I dont have to call for another plugin. Thanks!

Comment: @Guilherme - I have retested it and it's true they are not preloaded, the only thing imperative is to have 2 slides in the HTML. My solution has the advantage that you can insert a spinning symbol in case it has not loaded when the slide appears, with the before solution sometimes the slides are empty because they have not preloaded. That said, I upvote your answer.